# R: Fill the missing values if good inputs persist in data

Tags: r, data-mining, missing-data

Imagine a dataset:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(~Client, ~Client_ID, ~Year,  ~NPurchases,    ~Age,   ~Sex,   ~Hobby,
"Alex Smith",   88888,  2022,   NA, 30, "Male", "",
"Alex Smith",   88888,  2022,   45, 30, "Male", "Stamps",
"Alex Smith",   88888,  2021,   32, 29, "Male", "Stamps",
"Eugene Hugs",  788272, 2022,   2,  19, "Male", "Cats")
```

Or, the same dataset for visual representation:

[image]

The core columns are Client_ID and Year. For example, Alex Smith has two inputs for 2022.
Could you, please, suggest nice methods to:

1. Remove rows with more missing values
2. Find duplicated rows with different missing data, look at them (to see if there is no error), and then remove the rows with fewer data.

Any nice suggestions will be much appreciated :)

For example, my instant idea to solve was:

```
unique(rbindlist(list(df1))[!is.na(NPurchases), .(Client, Client_ID, Year, Age, NPurchases, Sex, Hobby)])
```

Output:
[image]

But I am sure there should be more universal and tidy methods :)

DESIRED OUTPUTS:

1. For the first variant:
   [image]
2. For the second variant:
   Similar solution that would provide the data on the rows it deleted.

There is a great solution by dplyr. Can you suggest other nice solutions?

Comment: Can you please add your expected output? What logic/rules are you trying to implement regarding missing values. Missing values only in the "core columns"? Or anywhere *other* than in the "core columns"? How do define missing values (`NA`, or `""` or ...)? What do you mean by "look at them and then remove the rows with fewer data"?

Comment: In the simplest variant, it should provide an output with the deleted first row (with missing data). Alternatively, it can show the issues with data that do not coincide (if any, and if they should). Say, if there would be another row for Alex 2022 with some data that do not match. But even a nice robust solution for the first problem would be great [I solved it not in R, but I would like to know suggestions about R :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you may try the below code which is without the filter_at

```r
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(sum=rowSums(across(everything(), ~(.x %in% c(NA, ' '))))) %>% 
filter(sum==0) %>% select(-sum)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Client      Client_ID  Year NPurchases   Age Sex   Hobby 
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1 Alex Smith      88888  2022         45    30 Male  Stamps
2 Alex Smith      88888  2021         32    29 Male  Stamps
3 Eugene Hugs    788272  2022          2    19 Male  Cats
```

Comment: Great idea, but I usually have many libraries run in R. I have errors. Can you, please, help with a fully robust solution? Here is error: > df1 %>% mutate(sum=rowSums(across(everything(), ~(.x %in% c(NA, ' '))))) %>% 
+ filter(sum==0)
Error in (function (cond)  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowSums': Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
> df1 %>% mutate(sum=rowSums(across(everything(), ~(.x %in% c(NA, ' '))))) %>% 
+ filter(sum==0) %>% select(-sum)
Error in select(., -sum) : unused argument (-sum)

Comment: An updated solution (works at any R environment): df2 <- df1 %>% dplyr::mutate(sum=rowSums(dplyr::across(dplyr::everything(), ~(.x %in% c(NA, ' '))))) %>% 
filter(sum==0) %>% select(-sum)

Answer (score 1):

Please try `filter_at` function from `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>% filter_at(vars(everything()), ~!(.x %in% c(NA, ' ')))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Client      Client_ID  Year NPurchases   Age Sex   Hobby 
  <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1 Alex Smith      88888  2022         45    30 Male  Stamps
2 Alex Smith      88888  2021         32    29 Male  Stamps
3 Eugene Hugs    788272  2022          2    19 Male  Cats
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a replicability issue: df2 <- df1 %>% filter_at(vars(everything()), ~!(.x %in% c(NA, ' ')))
Error:
! `everything()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html> for
  details.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Can you, please, suggest a robust solution no matter what libraries are in the system?

Comment: Here is my update for the solution that works robustly: df2 <- df1 %>% dplyr::filter_at(dplyr::vars(dplyr::everything()), ~!(.x %in% c(NA, ' ')))

Comment: if you call the `library(dplyr)` before the code, it will work without the `dplyr::`

Comment: That would be great, but: 
> 
> df2 <- df1 %>% filter_at(vars(everything()), ~!(.x %in% c(NA, ' ')))
Error:
! `everything()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html> for
  details.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: not sure, but i don't get any error